# Mailto not working if outlook instance is opened

Tags: outlook, mailto

I have created below HTML to test Mailto function. It works if i have not opened my outlook  instance in my computer whereas if my outlook instance is running , the below code doesn't work. 
I am using office 365 outlook desktop app.
Can anyone pls help where is the issue.

`<html>
<body>
<a href="mailto:name@gmail.com">Click here to mail</a></body>
</html>`

Regards,
Balakrishnan.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to change or set the default mail client application, see [How To Change Default Email Client](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555566) for more information.

To change the default e-mail client:-

1. Log on as Administrator
2. Open Internet Explorer, click the `Tools` menu, select `Internet Options`. Click `Programs` tab and select your email client from the drop-down list. Once selected, click `OK`/`Apply` button.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for your time. As mentioned issue is not with Default email client. If i have my outlook opened in my system the code doesn't work whereas if no instance of the outlook is running my machine the above code is working

Comment: Are your web page and Outlook run in the same security context?

Comment: Yes Eugine. Both are in same user context